# override builtin "and"

Tags: python, overriding

can the primitive "and" be overridden?
for instance If I try to do something like this

```
class foo():
    def __and__(self,other):
          return "bar"
```

this gets outputted

```
>> foo() and 4
4
>> foo().__and__(4)
'bar'
```

my intuition is that the built in and cannot be overridden and shouldn't be overridden to not cause confusion.

I guess the and function shouldn't be changed because it doesn't need to be, since it behaves like

```
def and(self,other):
    if( not bool(self) ):
           return self
    else:
           return other
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`__and__` overrides the bitwise operator `&`, not the logic operator.

To give your class boolean logic handling, define a `__nonzero__` method: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__

Answer (score 2):

The `and` operator cannot be overridden, since it doesn't always evaluate both of its operands.  There is no way to provide a function that can do what it does, arguments to functions are always fully evaluated before the function is invoked.  The same goes for `or`.

Comment: can you give me a case where both operands are not evaluated? I cannot think of one.

Comment: `x = False and foo()`.  If you write `foo()` to contain a `print` statement, you can easily see that it is never called. A Boolean `and` can never be true if one of its operands is false, and so if `and` knows the first operand is `False`, it never evaluates the second. `or` is the other way around: if the first operand is `True`, the second need not be evaluated. This is known as short-circuiting, and its side effects are sometimes used for their own sake: for example, `arg = arg or default` will assign the value `default` to `arg` if `arg` is empty, zero, or `None`.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean `and` and `or` can't be overridden in Python. It is true that they have special behavior (short-circuiting, such that both operands are not always evaluated) and this has something to do with why they are not overrideable. However, this is not (IMHO) the whole story.

In fact, Python *could* provide a facility that supports short-circuiting while still allowing the `and` and `or` operators to be overridden; it simply does not do so. This may be a deliberate choice to keep things simple, or it may be because there are other things the Python developers think would be more useful to developers and are working on them instead.

However, it is a choice on the part of Python's designers, not a law of nature.